# How to insert video from a video folder into joomla article using xampp

Tags: joomla-3.x

please help. Am working on joomla on xampp, so a created a folder in media called "videos" were i have placed some videos. now my problem is to get to those videos from a article. please help me!!!! my codes are as follows

```
<video height="240" width="320">
<source src="/images/videos/myVideo.wmv" type="video/wmv"/>
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem in your path (remove the first slash) also except the wmv problem.

```
<video height="240" width="320">
<source src="images/videos/myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

I am assuming that images folder is in the same directory as index.php.

Answer (score 0):

The `WMV` format is not supported with HTML5 videos, so I would suggest converting your video to MP4 and OGG, then use the following:

```
<video height="240" width="320">
    <source src="/images/videos/myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="/images/videos/myVideo.ogv" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: Thanks so much Bro , i get it. But is the a better way of putting videos on my joomla site where my videos are in a local folder apart from hand coding html5?

Comment: There are loads of extensions that you can use, that will allow you to upload and manage your videos, then embed a short code snippet to render the video. So you can either do that, of store you videos like you're currently doing. Either way if perfectly fine.

Comment: please which of them do you recommend i use?

Comment: Perhaps this: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/sj-simple-html5-video-player

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned the wmv is not recommended. For whatever reasons, I have noticed many Joomla! video plugins do not offer local file playback, which is odd.

If you are looking for a decent playback solution, which can play single videos and/or create video galleries with multiple playback solutions and for the most part only requires a simple syntax (shortcode) then take a look at

Yendif Player: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/yendif-video-share

and

All Video Share: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/allvideoshare

Both have 5 star reviews on Joomla! Extensions Directory website and I believe made by the same people or friends. Both are free but also offer paid versions.

Again, both offer many options such as categories, meta info, SEF Urls, fixed dimensions, images, captions, related videos and a multitude of customizable property settings which also includes css styling.

They both use a default flash player, that can play HD videos and both come with an HTML5 video player fallback.

Either one will work for your needs and the good thing of both is, you can use it as a simple video player plugin or an extensive video collection nicely presented.